# How is the asymptotic justification of the "linearization by influence function method" for surveys established?

Tags: sampling, asymptotics, measure-theory, survey-sampling, influence-function

The `survey` R package recently adopted the "linearization by influence function" method of estimating covariances between domain estimates. The central paper justifying this method is [Deville (1999)](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/12-001-x/1999002/article/4882-eng.pdf). I'm trying to understand the main asymptotic claim made in the paper and some confusing aspects of the proof.

The result is summarized concisely by Deville and others in [this 2009 Biometrika paper](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/96/3/691/255716?login=true):

> In Deville's approach, a population parameter of interest $\Phi$ can be written as a functional $T$ with respect to a finite and discrete measure $M$, namely $\Phi=T(M)$. The substitution estimator $\hat{\Phi}=T(\hat{M})$ is the functional $T$ of a random measure $\hat{M}$ that is associated with sampling weights $w_{k}, k \in U$, and is 'close' to $M$. Suppose that $T$ is homogeneous of degree $\alpha$, so that $T(r M)=r^{\alpha} T(M)$, and $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} N^{-\alpha} T(M)<\infty$. Under broad assumptions, Deville shows that
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \sqrt{n} N^{-\alpha}\{T(\hat{M})-T(M)\} &=\sqrt{n} N^{-\alpha} \int I_{T}(M, z) d(\hat{M}-M)(z)+o_{p}(1) \\
> &=\sqrt{n} N^{-\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^{N} u_{k}\left(w_{k}-1\right)+o_{p}(1)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> The linearized variables $u_{k}$ are the influence functions $I_{T}\left(M, z_{k}\right)$, where $z_{k}$ is the value of the variable of interest for the $k$ th unit.

This exact equation doesn't show up in Deville's 1999 paper as far as I can see. Instead, there is a tantalizingly similar-looking result on page 6.

> Result: Under broad assumptions, the substitution estimation of a functional $T(M)$ is linearizable. A linearized variable is $z_{k}=I T\left(M ; x_{k}\right)$ where $I T$ is the influence function of $T$ in $M$.
>
> Proof of the result: Let us provide the space of measurements on $\boldsymbol{R}^{q}$ with a metric $d$ accounting for the convergence: $d\left(M_{1}, M_{2}\right) \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $N^{-1}\left(\int y d M_{1}-\int y d M_{2}\right) \rightarrow 0$ for any variable of interest $y$. The asymptotic postulates mean that $d(\hat{M} / N, M / N)$ tends towards zero. We can visibly ensure that $d(\hat{M} / N, M / N)$ is $O_{p}(1 / \sqrt{n})$ according to the third postulate. Now, let us assume that $T$ can be derived in accordance with Fréchet, i.e., for any direction of the increase, in the space of "useful" measures provided with the abovementioned metric. Thus we have:
> $$
> N^{-\alpha}(T(\hat{M})-T(M))=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{U} z_{k}\left(w_{k}-1\right)+o\left(d\left(\frac{\hat{M}}{M}, \frac{M}{N}\right)\right)
> $$
> The result is that:
> $$
> \sqrt{n} N^{-\alpha}(T(\hat{M})-T(M))=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{N} \sum_{U} z_{k}\left(w_{k}-1\right)+o_{p}(1) .
> $$

However, this result in the original 1999 paper is not the same result as the 2009 Biometrika paper. **Why does the right-hand side of the Deville 1999 equation use $N^{-1}$, while the right-hand side of the quoted equation in the 2009 paper uses $N^{-\alpha}$?**

The equation in Deville 1999 doesn't make sense to me. For example, the mean is a statistic of degree 0 and its influence function is $z_{k}=\frac{1}{N}\left(y_{k}-\bar{Y}\right)$, so with the Deville 1999 equation we would end up with the nonsensical result that
$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\bar{Y}} - \bar{Y}) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{N} \left[\hat{\bar{Y}} - \bar{Y}(\frac{\hat{N}}{N}) \right] + o_p(1)$.

And the proof seems to contain some hidden steps. **How is that first equation in Deville 1999 derived?** It seems to involve the following missing step, but it's not clear how even this equation would be established.

$$
N^{-\alpha}(T(\hat{M})-T(M))= N^{-1} \int I_{T}(M, z) d(\hat{M}-M)(z)+o\left(d\left(\frac{\hat{M}}{M}, \frac{M}{N}\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Deville 1999 paper does have a typo there when it comes to $N^{-1}$ vs. $N^{-\alpha}$. A couple of subsequent papers contain clearer, more detailed proofs in their appendices: [Goga, Deville, and Ruiz-Gazen, 2009](https://www.tse-fr.eu/sites/default/files/medias/doc/by/ruiz_gazen/gogadevilleruizgazen_2009.pdf), and [Goga and Ruiz-Gazen 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1375). [This blog post I wrote](https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/establishing-the-influence-function-methods-asymptotic-validity/) contains a fairly detailed walk-through of the proof from the 2009 paper linked above. This StackExchange answer represents a condensed version of the blog post.

#### Assumptions of the theorem

The first set of assumptions (1 through 4) apply to the sample design and must apply to each variable of interest, $\mathcal{Z}$.

- **Assumption 1**.
  We assume that $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} N^{-1} n = f\in(0,1)$.
- **Assumption 2** .
  We assume that $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} N^{-1} \int \mathcal{Z} d M$ exists, for any variable of interest $\mathcal{Z}$.
- **Assumption 3**.
  As $N \rightarrow \infty$, we have that $N^{-1}\left(\int \mathcal{Z} d \hat{M}-\int \mathcal{Z} d M\right) \rightarrow 0$ in probability, for any variable of interest $\mathcal{Z}$.
- **Assumption 4**.
  As $N \rightarrow \infty,\left\{\sqrt{n} N^{-1}\left(\int \mathcal{Z} d \hat{M}-\int \mathcal{Z} d M\right)\right\} \rightarrow N(0, \Sigma)$ in distribution, for any variable of interest $\mathcal{Z}$.

The second set of assumptions, 5 through 7, apply to the functional $T$, requiring it to be "smooth" in a certain sense and to be bounded in a certain sense.

- **Assumption 5**.
  We assume that $T$ is homogeneous, in that there exists a real number $\beta>0$ dependent on $T$ such that $T(r M)=r^{\beta} T(M)$ for any real $r>0$.
- **Assumption 6**.
  We assume that $\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} N^{-\beta} T(M)<\infty$.
- **Assumption 7**.
  We assume that $T$ is Fréchet differentiable.

#### Statement of Theorem

Let $u_k$ denote the influence function for element $k$ in the population (i.e. if person $k$ has values $z_k$, then $u_k=IT(M;z_k)$), and let $v_k$ denote the sampling weight for person $k$ in the population. If person $k$ is in a selected sample, then $v_k=1/\pi_k$, where $\pi_k$ is their probability of inclusion in the sample. For persons in the population but not in the selected sample, $v_k=0$.

If Assumptions 1 through 7 hold, then:

$$
\begin{aligned}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{N^{\beta}}\{T(\hat{M})-T(M)\} &=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{N^{\beta}} \int IT(M ; z) d\left(\hat{M}-M\right)(z)+o_{p}(1) \\&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{N^{\beta}} \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{N} u_{k}\left(v_{k}-1\right)\right\}+o_{p}(1)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\textit{and so the asymptotic variance of }\\T(\hat{M})\textit{ is equal to the variance of }\\ \sum_{k=1}^{N} u_{k}\left(v_{k}-1\right)
$$

#### Proof

Below is a condensed version of that post:

From Assumptions 5 (homogeneity of $T$), we have that $N^{-\beta}T(M)=T(M/N)$.
From Assumption 6, we have that $T(M/N)=N^{-\beta}T(M) < \infty$ for sufficiently large $N$.
Taken together, this implies that for sufficiently large $N$, the following holds:

$$
\begin{aligned}{N^{-\beta}}\{T(\hat{M})-T(M)\} &= T(\frac{\hat{M}}{N}) - T(\frac{M}{N}) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Let us provide the space $(\mathbb{R}^p, M)$ with the metric $\tilde{d}$ satisfying $d(Q/N, M/N) \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $N^{-1} \{ \int Z dQ(z) - \int Z dM(z) \} \rightarrow 0$ for any variable of interest $Z$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^p$.
This means that the distance between the sample's measure $\hat{M}$ and the population's measure $M$ goes to zero if and only if the distance between the population total (i.e. $\int Z dM(z)= \sum_{k \in U} z_k$) and the Horvitz-Thompson estimator for the total (i.e. $\int Z d\hat{M}(z)= \sum_{k \in s} z_k/\pi_k$) goes to zero for any variable of interest.

From Assumption 4, then, we have that $\tilde{d}(\hat{M}/N, M/N) = O_p(n^{-1/2})$.

Now because $T$ is Fréchet differentiable by Assumption 7, we can write the following first-order von-Mises expansion (see Huber 1981 pages 35-39 for details):

$$
\begin{aligned}T(\frac{\hat{M}}{N}) &= T(\frac{M}{N}) + \int IT(\frac{M}{N} ; z) d\left(\frac{\hat{M}}{N}-\frac{M}{N}\right)(z) + o\{ \tilde{d}(\hat{M}/N, M/N) \}
 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Next, we note that for a functional of degree $\beta$, $IT(\frac{M}{N};z)=N^{1-\beta} IT(M,z)$ (proof in Deville, 1999).
So we thus have that:

$$
\begin{aligned}T(\frac{\hat{M}}{N}) - T(\frac{M}{N}) &=  N^{-\beta} \int IT(M ; z) d\left(\hat{M}-M\right)(z) + o\{ \tilde{d}(\hat{M}/N, M/N) \}
 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Denote the remainder term $R_n$.
Now since we have that $\tilde{d}(\hat{M}/N, M/N)$ is $O_p(n^{-1/2})$, and $R_n$ is $o\left(\tilde{d}(\hat{M}/N, M/N)\right)$, we must have that $R_n=o_p(n^{-1/2})$.

And so we have that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
T(\frac{\hat{M}}{N}) - T(\frac{M}{N}) &=  N^{-\beta} \int IT(M ; z) d\left(\hat{M}-M\right)(z) + o_p( n^{-1/2} )
 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{n}$, we thus have that:

$$
\sqrt{n} \left( T(\frac{\hat{M}}{N}) - T(\frac{M}{N}) \right) = \sqrt{n}N^{-\beta} \int IT(M ; z) d\left(\hat{M}-M\right)(z) + o_p(1)
$$

This gives us the desired result:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{n} N^{-\beta}\left( T(\hat{M}) - T(M) \right) &= \sqrt{n}N^{-\beta} \int IT(M ; z) d\left(\hat{M}-M\right)(z) + o_p(1) \\
&= \sqrt{n}N^{-\beta} \sum_{k=1}^{N} u_k(v_k - 1) + o_p(1)
\end{aligned}
$$